# Need to prevent repeating characters using RegEx

Tags: regex, string, match, string-matching

How can I use RegEx to test for the following pattern:

1. String must be 4-10 characters long
2. String must not have any repeating
   characters (no two characters can be the same and be next to each other)

I have researched this and I think I am close with:

```
^(?!(.)\1).{4,10}$
```

This will correctly find a match for both `ab12` and `12ab`. It also correctly rejects `1111` and `aaaa`. However it wrongly accepts `12aa` and `ab11`.

It seems to only look for the repeating characters at the beginning of the string. I have tried to move or remove the `^` and the `$`, but I need them for the max character check. I have also tried several variations of `(.)\1` to find repeating characters with no luck.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

PS - In case someone knows the answer, I actually want to allow a maximum of one pair of repeating characters but I decided this was too hard and decided to just disallow any repeating characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can precede the capturing group inside of the lookahead assertion with a greedy quantifier.

The `.*` matches all the characters to the very end of the string.

```
^(?!.*(.)\1).{4,10}$
```

Comment: Thanks hwnd! This worked for me, and I was able to add other restrictions to it. I wanted to keep the question simple, but my final expression was ^(?!.*(.)\1.*(.)\2)(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=.*[0-9]).{4,10}$

Comment: Paul, thank you so much for the extra tip. I added your tweak and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the best way to do it would be:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1)){4,10}$
```

The reason why being that a long string will fail faster.

Comment: pguardiario thanks for the great answer. This did work for the question I asked, and I trust it is faster. However I preferred the answer hwnd provided because I could expand on it.